# Can't find snap-in in MMC

Tags: mmc, snap-in

I try to register a sample of snap-in that was developed by Microsoft but I can't see it in the Add\Remove menu.

I use Win7 x64, the project is defined to x64 and I used InstallUtil.exe to install the DLL. According to the log the installation completed successfully.

I have no clue why I don't see it in the Add/Remove menu. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

On a x64 Windows you should also use the 64-bit version of the `InstallUtil.exe`with is located in the `Framework64` subfolder (i.e. '`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`).